# Change keyboard navigation order with element outside Highcharts React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, accessibility, keyboard-navigation

I have a Chart component, created with Highcharts, which looks like this:

```
<div className={scss.chartContainer}>
                {!hideContextMenu && (
                    <div className={scss.contextMenu}>
                        <ChartContextMenu
                            contextMenuLabel={`${contextMenuForLabel} ${defaultChartTitle}`}
                            enhancedContrastState={[a11yModeEnabled, toggleA11yMode]}
                            enhancedContrastLabel={contextMenuEnhancedContrastLabel}
                            enhancedContrastTooltip={contextMenuEnhancedContrastTooltip}
                            tableViewState={[showDataTable, setShowDataTable]}
                            tableViewLabel={contextMenuTableViewLabel}
                            tableViewTooltip={contextMenuTableViewTooltip}
                        />
                    </div>
                )}
                <HighchartsReact
                    containerProps={{
                        "data-component": "chart",
                        "data-observe-key": props["data-observe-key"],
                        className: className,
                        style: style,
                    }}
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={chartOptions}
                    ref={chartComponentRef}
                />
            </div>
```

Which looks like this (the `ChartContextMenu` is the cogwheel button on the right)
[image]

Ok, so to my problem:
Currently, in terms of accessibility, the keyboard navigation is:

1. Cogwheel button
2. Legend
3. Series

And that totally makes sense, because the div order (`ChartContextMenu` is before the chart), and the keyboard navigation within Highcharts is

```
keyboardNavigation: {
                order: ["legend", "series"],
            },
```

**But I require to change this order, making the legend as 1st, followed by the cogwheel button, and last the series.**
**How can I change this order? Like, I need to put a div that is outside the actual chart in the middle of the chart order**
**Required order:**
**1. Legend**
**2. Cogwheel button**
**3. Series**

I have tried using `tabIndex` attribute within the divs to test it, but couldn't find a way to make it work..

**Edit:**
I'm trying to follow the example from Highcharts API about Accessibility Custom Components, but I'm having some trouble with it:
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/accessibility/custom-component

My code:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
const HighchartsContextMenu = function (this: any, chart: any) {
    this.initBase(chart);
    return (
        <>
            {!hideContextMenu && (
                <div className={scss.contextMenu}>
                    <ChartContextMenu
                        contextMenuLabel={`${contextMenuForLabel} ${defaultChartTitle}`}
                        enhancedContrastState={[a11yModeEnabled, toggleA11yMode]}
                        enhancedContrastLabel={contextMenuEnhancedContrastLabel}
                        enhancedContrastTooltip={contextMenuEnhancedContrastTooltip}
                        tableViewState={[showDataTable, setShowDataTable]}
                        tableViewLabel={contextMenuTableViewLabel}
                        tableViewTooltip={contextMenuTableViewTooltip}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    );
};
HighchartsContextMenu.prototype = new Highcharts.AccessibilityComponent();
const element = (
        <>
            <SrOnly>
                <Link href={`#${skipChartAnchorId}`}>{i18n.skipChart}</Link>
            </SrOnly>
            <div className={scss.chartContainer}>
                <HighchartsContextMenu />
                <HighchartsReact
                    containerProps={{
                        "data-component": "chart",
                        "data-observe-key": props["data-observe-key"],
                        className: className,
                        style: style,
                    }}
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={chartOptions}
                    ref={chartComponentRef}
                />
            </div>
```

in the options:

```
accessibility: {
            landmarkVerbosity: "disabled",
            point: {
                dateFormat: "%B %e, %Y",
            },
            screenReaderSection: {
                beforeChartFormat: beforeChartFormatTemplate,
                onViewDataTableClick: undefined,
            },
            customComponents: {
                chartContextMenu: ChartContextMenu,
            },
            keyboardNavigation: {
                order: ["legend", "chartContextMenu", "series"],
            },
        },
```

The error:
**`TypeError: this is undefined`**

Also, talking about the example, they create some functions extending Highcharts to config the button.. but since it's a custom component, do I have to do that as well? I'm kinda lost on this one

Comment: You need to add your component as an `accessibility.customComponents` .  Then you will be able to use it in `keyboardNavigation.order` . Demo JS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t86yn2uj/ . API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/accessibility.customComponents If you will need help with implementation in React , please reproduce your config into the simplified demo, that I could work on. Regards!

Comment: @magdalena this is awesome! it's probably exactly what I need, but I'm running into some typescript issues, not sure if it's the correct way to do it, because it's not creating a simple button like the example from Highcharts API.. I'll edit the post to add my current solution and problem

Comment: To use React components you have to convert them to HTML by using `renderToString` or `renderToStaticMarkup` methods, or use portals and render components into already existing chart elements. Docs: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-react-component-to-a-charts-element Useful thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/23